# Convert embedded object(EMBED_OBJECT) to Attachment

Tags: lotusscript

I am currently looking for a solution to convert existing EMBED_OBJECT in Lotus Notes Document to EMBED_ATTACHMENT.
What I plan to do is extracting the EMBEDDED_OBJECT from its original path and then re-attach it on "Body1".

I found below example from googling and it is working fine but only for ATTACHMENT. Still did not find a way to apply it on EMBED_OBJECT type.

When I go through the code during debugging, the property embobj.SOURCE get the names like "AT0050" instead of full original path.

May I know what should I do to achieve my goals?

thanks a lot

Set item = doc.GetFirstItem("Body1")

```
    Forall embobj In item.EmbeddedObjects           
        verbs = "No verbs"          
        Select Case embobj.Type

            Case EMBED_OBJECTLINK : _

            embobjType = "Object link"

            Case EMBED_ATTACHMENT : _

            embobjType = "Attachment"
            Call embobj.ExtractFile( "c:\" &  embobj.source)

                Case EMBED_OBJECT : embobjType = "Object"

        End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

The embedded objects don't have a "filename". What kind of objects are they? Just office documents? For office documents you could open the object and save the file through office automation and attach the file again with the correct filetype.

Comment: They can be any, office documents or PDF.

Comment: Activate the embedded object. Figure out what kind of com object it returned. Than save the document to temporary location with correct file extension and attach it to the notesdocument.